# Toolbar back button in single activity

Tags: java, android

How can I implement this back button, when I have only 1 Activity (MainActivity) and lots of fragments and also fragments, that call another fragments. 
 [image: Toolbar]

So far I tried this bellow, but I think this works only for activities:

```
 Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_navigationdrawer);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Comment: You have to specify Android SDK version, gradle support and UI framework that you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you apple AppCompatActivity, then here is my proposed way-out to work dynamic layout. You can add the buttons and change title afterwards

```
   this.supportActionBar!!.displayOptions =  ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM
        this.supportActionBar!!.setCustomView(R.layout.toolbar_title)
        val title = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tvTitle)
        title.text = resources.getString(R.string.user_login)
```

As fragment back pressing function, you have to specify the page structure. If there are tabs within your activity, the action of back press shall be designed carefully.

Do not expect me to answer more. Even a college student can manage to understand the basic principles of Android UI and code as similar to what I have given.